# Saving an image (retrieved from external library) locally - Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm really really new to Angular and all. So I've gotten a QR code image from a library (angularx-qrcode) generator.

Here's the code to get the image:

```
     <qrcode [qrdata]="'Your QR code data string'" [size]="256" [level]="'M'"></qrcode>
```

Now I wanna have a button that allows the user to save the above image locally. How can I achieve this?

Also is the syntax different for different Angular versions (e.g. 2 vs 7)?

Thank you so much!! any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to download the Qr code image into your local device, check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularx-qrcode-download-qrcode-image).

This is my approach:

- First, you need to get the base64 image data from the generated image
- Convert the base 64 encoded image into blob data
- Add a button to download the image

**Your `component.html` can be something like this:~**

```
<qrcode #parent [qrdata]="qrdata" [size]="256" [level]="'M'"></qrcode>
<br>
<button (click)="saveAsImage(parent)">Download QR Code Image</button>
```

**Your `component.ts` can be something like this:~**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  qrdata = 'Initial QR code data string';

  saveAsImage(parent) {
    // fetches base 64 date from image
    const parentElement = parent.el.nativeElement.querySelector("img").src;

    // converts base 64 encoded image to blobData
    let blobData = this.convertBase64ToBlob(parentElement);

    // saves as image
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { //IE
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobData, 'Qrcode');
    } else { // chrome
      const blob = new Blob([blobData], { type: "image/png" });
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      // window.open(url);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.download = 'Qrcode';
      link.click();
    }

  }

  private convertBase64ToBlob(Base64Image: any) {
    // SPLIT INTO TWO PARTS
    const parts = Base64Image.split(';base64,');
    // HOLD THE CONTENT TYPE
    const imageType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    // DECODE BASE64 STRING
    const decodedData = window.atob(parts[1]);
    // CREATE UNIT8ARRAY OF SIZE SAME AS ROW DATA LENGTH
    const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(decodedData.length);
    // INSERT ALL CHARACTER CODE INTO UINT8ARRAY
    for (let i = 0; i < decodedData.length; ++i) {
      uInt8Array[i] = decodedData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    // RETURN BLOB IMAGE AFTER CONVERSION
    return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: imageType });
  }

}
```

*(For the function `convertBase64ToBlob`, credits to [Kaushik Parmar](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55257089/2))*

Also, if you want to save the text inside the QRCode check [this other stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularx-qrcode-download-qrcode-text).

Comment: that seems like what I would like to achieve, thank you so much for your help!! :D

Comment: Hey Sourav, I'm so sorry to bother - do you know if it's possible to download the QR Code as a pdf? if it is, would i have to convert the qr image to a base64 encoded pdf file instead of an image? thanks!

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filixix/0816jdfq/)! Try to modify the answer accordingly :) hope this helps !