# Saving an image (from an external library) to a PDF file locally in Angular7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm new to the Angular/Typescript language.

I have a qrcode img that is generated from an external qrcode generator library (angularx-qrcode). I would like to have a code that allows the user to generate this qr code and save it as a PDF file locally.

I've made a similar question but it's having to save the qrcode as a PNG image: [Saving an image (retrieved from external library) locally - Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979501/saving-an-image-retrieved-from-external-library-locally-angular)

This is the code in which I've gotten from other sources:

```
  showPdf(parent) {
    const parentElement = parent.el.nativeElement.querySelector("img").src;
    console.log(parentElement);
    const pdfInBase64 = parentElement;
    const newBlob = new Blob([pdfInBase64], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob); // For IE browser
    }
    const linkElement = document.createElement('a');
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
    linkElement.setAttribute('download', 'sample.pdf');
    const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
      'view': window,
      'bubbles': true,
     'cancelable': false
    });
    linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
  }
```

This code allows me to download the PDF file, but when I try to view the file on adobe, an error shows: "Adobe cannot open the file because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged".

Can someone help me with this please? thank you so much!!